# Modifying a JAR file with updated class file

Tags: java, jar

I have a .jar file and need to modify some classes within it. I'm not exactly sure how the author compiled everything, as I'm not much of an app developer. But I have some of the source code for one of his packages. Would it be possible for me to modify a .java file, compile it into a .class file, and swap it out with the one in the .jar?

Comment: A JAR file is a zip file with a different extension. Rename to .zip, unzip, change, zip, rename to .jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Unless the JAR is cryptographically signed and it's signature verified at runtime (some containers do verify the jar file signatures if there are any), you can swap binary class files in the jar file. You'll need to make sure not to break binary compatibility with the existing classes though, if you don't want to run into errors at runtime. The .jar file is practically a ZIP file with a `.jar` extension.

Answer (score 0):

A jar file is just a zip file so of you are just recompiling you should have no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can unzip the jar file using an utility like 7-zip and replace the ".class" file you want with the newly compiled one.